# How to use datacontract in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this interface both in server and client side:

```
namespace BH_Server {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface BHInterface {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetName( string name );
        [OperationContract]
        Device GetDevice();
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Device {
        private string dSN;
        [DataMember]
        public string SN {
            get { return dSN; }
            set { dSN = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have this in server side:

```
public class CronServiceInterface : BHInterface {
  public string GetName( string name ) {
        return string.Format( "Hello {0}", name );
  }
  public Device GetDevice() {
        Device d = new Device();
        d.SN = "123456789";
        return d;
    }
}
```

And this on server side, also:

```
host = new ServiceHost( typeof( CronServiceInterface ), new Uri[] {
    new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/")
} );
host.AddServiceEndpoint( typeof( BHInterface ), new NetNamedPipeBinding( NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None ), "BhPipe" );
host.Open();
```

To create connection on client side, this code is used:

```
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding( NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None );
ChannelFactory<BHInterface> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<BHInterface>( binding );
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress( "net.pipe://localhost/BhPipe/" );
BHInterface iface = channelFactory.CreateChannel( endpointAddress );
```

Obviously not all the code is written here, I hope it is enough to see what is implemented.

Using `Debug.WriteLine( iface.GetName("Tom") );` results "Hello Tom" in client side, but the following code won't work:

```
Device d;
d = iface.GetDevice();
Debug.WriteLine( string.Format( "Printing sn: {0}", d.SN ) );
```

It prints: "Printing sn: ".

I'm using .NET 4.5 and error is not thrown. I'm new in WCF topic.

Would somebody so kind explaining to me how could I pass the desired object to client?

Comment: What if you just use `public string SN { get; set; }`?

Comment: there are numerous examples on how DataContracts work online have you thought to do a simple google search..?

Comment: Dear @MethodMan of cuurse I tried Google it, thanks for your valueable comment ;)

Comment: @roncsak I'm curious then ..what did you search on..because I can see 100's of examples on the subject..

Comment: @DionV. still empty :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, I found out!

I had to use attributes in my datacontracts!

```
namespace BH_Server {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface BHInterface {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetName( string name );
        [OperationContract]
        Device GetDevice();
    }
    [DataContract( Name = "Device", Namespace = "" )]
    public class Device {

        [DataMember( Name = "SN", Order = 1 )]
        public string SN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this just remove the backing field for your property and have `DataContract` defined as

```
[DataContract]
public class Device {
    [DataMember]
    public string SN {get;set;}
}
```

The reason is that the value of `dSN` is not sent from the service to the client because it is not a `[DataMember]`. Other solution would be mark the private field with `[DataMember]` attribute but you should generally avoid such practice.

Also , remember to update service reference after any change to the data contracts as otherwise client will still see old contracts.

Comment: I've tried this, for some reason it is still empty. :(

Comment: but have you updated references in your project ? Every change to `DataContract` requires service ref to be updated

Comment: Yes, I updated both files. However, I did not added refernces to the project at all (I mean, I've seen some example where they added references but I could not understand them). So, there is no reference in the client project to the server one. I'm using WCF interface programmatically. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit more... Like the ServiceContract and OperationContract shows the prototypes veses implementation, so goes for the DataContract and DataMembers.  You are placing implementation

```
get { return dSN; }
set { dSN = value; }
```

Where all is needed is the

```
public string SN {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it did not helped. :( Please see the comment at tchrikch's suggestion.